# Position of a point as seen by a circle

Tags: c

Program to find out position of the point with respect to a circle whose centre and radius are input. I came up with the code given below, but for some reason only the first printf and scanf statements are executed and rest of the statements are ignored.

```
//point wrt a circle
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    //input radius and centre
    float r,x,y,f,g,d;
    printf("Enter centre's x,y and radius: ");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&f,g,&r);

    printf("enter the x y of the point");
    scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);

    //formula for distance
    d=pow(pow((x-f),2)+pow((y-g),2),0.5);

    //comparing d with r
    if (r==d)
        printf("on the circle");
    else if(r<d)
        printf("outside the circle");
    else
        printf("Inside the circle");
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal asks me to input the radius and centre's coordinates and that's it!
Please help me understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Did you look at and heed the warnings your compiler is emitting for that code?

Comment: there are no warnings and no errors.

Comment: Then enable strict warnings on your compiler. See how `-Wall` can tell you exactly what's wrong? https://godbolt.org/z/TjPbh5sv5

Comment: In practice, `if (r==d)` have few chance to get `true`, because of rounding errors. You could compare `fabs(r-d)` to a threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%f%f%f",&f,g,&r);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%f%f%f",&f,&g,&r);
```